# Closing Modal when using ajax and validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

i have run into a little issue for closing a data modal with bootstrap i have showed a bit of code below basically at the current stage the ajax validates the form via the input submit field this works however it doesn't close the modal it resides in

so my question how can i utilize the same ajax code but allowing the data modal to close on submission please bare in mind the modals id is webapp_customers_modal but is dynamic with a number on the end as its used in multiple places

this is the preferred method i would like to use but doesn't submit the form

```
<button type='submit' data-dismiss='modal'data dismiss='modal'>Save</button>
```

This is the current form submit im using this works but doesn't close the modal

```
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' value='Save' >
```

this is the ajax code

```
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $('form.frm_details').on('submit', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/limitless/functions2.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',                       
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                      success: function(data) {
                           if(data.status == '1')
                            {
                                $('#info').addClass('alert alert-danger no-border').html(data.message);
                            } 
                           if(data.status == '2')
                            {
                                $('#info').addClass('alert alert-danger no-border').html(data.message);
                                webapp_get_customers(); 
                            }                               
                        }  
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have one of your modals open at a time you can add a common class, like **my-modals** to them and then use this in you script. This way you don't need to keep track of your dynamic created id's.

```
$('.my-modals').modal('hide');
```

Comment: hey mate this could work how would you implement this into the modal code

Comment: Just add it to your script where you want the modal to close. Do you want it to close immediately on form submission or first when the result is back from your ajax request?

Comment: Sorry, read your question one more time. Just place it after event.preventDefault(); in your form submission event handler

Answer (score 0):

Why not close modal using javascript? Give your modal an Id

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide'); //This closes modal with id 'myModal'
```

PS: you can add the above code inside success callback.

Comment: this wouldnt work as there could be upto 10 modals on the page all with and id appened onto the id